# Work from home despite new company directive?

Tags: company-policy, telecommute

We have been working from home for 2 years due to COVID-19.
I personally set up a home office and workshop, with all tools, debuggers, PC, software, to keep going 100% and more.
I develop electronics and firmware.
We use teams to chat, call, collaborate, share screens etc.

The company uses scrum and other systems to measure performance.
Our scrum metrics and performance went way up and up during WFH.

A little while back, the company asked for 2 days in the office,
Interestingly, the scrum metrics and performance have decreased since.
I go into the office but when there, it is like a holiday.
I cannot do much real work in an open plan office like this anymore. Funny that.

Today, they now said we need to come 3 days per week.

I do not want to do that as the office seriously makes me depressed and hampers my style of working.
I have no issue going there anytime when needed for something or when I feel I need to do something on site.

I am now considering just to ignore the directive and keep working from home for 3 days instead of 2.
I produce excellent work this way and received a great bonus recently with a top review. There are zero issues with anything I do and only praise.

What would the likely consequences be of me just carrying on as before?

When it says on the Internet that employees are resisting, what does this mean?

Comment: What does it matter what random people on internet says about this? Talk to your manager.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to formally push back against this?

Comment: The consequences range from "nothing" to "you are fired immediately". Nobody here can tell you what _your specific employer_ will do.

Comment: You really, really need to add your country.

Comment: "There a zero issues with anything I do and only praise."  That probably will no longer be the case if you follow through with your plan.

Comment: *"When it says on the Internet that employees are resisting, what does this mean?"* Normally the articles making this statement go on to explain what they mean but they are likely talking about: complaining to management, making a case to be an exception, quitting to work at remote companies, and refusing offers/interviews at companies that don't allow remote work.

Answer (score 4):

Do not, I repeat, Do not **"ignore"** an official directive, you can always discuss about it.

First of all, talk to your manager and show the metrics you mentioned about. As you say, the productivity is higher and the communication is not an issue, I do not see any reason why a reasonable manager will decline your request to continue the existing working arrangement.

If they deny, you need to consider whether that is a ground enough to look for opportunities elsewhere, where they would accommodate your request.

Answer (score 4):

> What would the likely consequences be of me just carrying on as
> before?

It's really difficult for us to predict the likely consequence. There are range of factors at play here.

> When it says on the internet that employees are resisting, what does
> this mean?

It means employees are refusing, or somewhat refusing to come back to the office. We can't possibly know if the range of actions that means "resist" will work well for you.

What I would say is some companies will happily take a performance hit of some employees in order to enact a widespread change that they think will overall increase productivity. While you may be working better, it's possible some junior employees are working less efficiently because they don't have someone they can ask for help.

Comment: +1 Good point regarding the juniors

Comment: @morsor While I agree in general,  in this case I believe OP mentioned he scrum metrics went up, which indicates that majority side was o positive.

Comment: @SouravGhosh that assumes scrum metrics measure anything meaningful...

Comment: @PhilipKendall :) meaningful or not, that's the most used KPI.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not everything is measured in scrum metrics.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie My point was, scrum metrics is for the whole team, especially when OP said "ours" and not "mine".

Comment: @SouravGhosh The team metrics can go up, AND the junior can not be improving and getting the help they need at the same time. I know if I ignore juniors in my team the team productivity will go up. But obviously there is a lack of growth in the team.

Comment: _"I know if I ignore juniors in my team the team productivity will go up"_. I'm sorry, that is anything but a team.

Comment: @SouravGhosh QED